# What am I doing wrong that is causing this graph to scroll incorrectly?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a simple Java program that takes a math function as input and displays a 2D (x and y) graph in a JPanel. I've got the graph displaying correctly initially.
I tried adding scrolling to the canvas (I called the JPanel subclass I made a GraphCanvas), by which I mean that when the mouse is dragged across it, the 2D plane scrolls as well and the graph is updated for the newly revealed areas. 
To display this actual function, I am using a Path2D object that is made up of segments connecting enough points so that the graph is in maximum resolution, and I've been using AffineTransforms to translate the path. 
It's worth noting that I've only tested the program so far with functions in the form f(x), and not parametrics, even though I've created a class and supporting code in the GraphedInstance class for parametric functions. 
I didn't want to include all of the code for the project, but I pushed it to a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/pammons/Graphing2D) (I have very little knowledge of how GitHub works but that should be right).

My problem is that at the moment, whenever I try to scroll the graph, the function just kind of does its own thing and doesn't connect correctly with the initialized piece. It isn't displaying the newly generated parts correctly.

I've done some work on it and improved the problem significantly by waiting to transform the path describing the function until after I've added the new pieces to it, but it still doesn't connect correctly.

This is the method that is supposed to create and stitch together the new parts of the function path, and it's where I think the issue probably lies. This and the rest of the project can also be found in the GitHub repository. Also, sorry for any messy code and/or lack of comments, I'm only a freshman in college and haven't really had any formal training in Java, I've just kind of picked it up as I go along. I would be happy to take any suggestions or recommendations of better ways to do anything as well!

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class Minimal {

    private static int[] lastPointer = new int[2];
    private static double xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    private static double xScale, yScale;
    private static double minXGraphed, maxXGraphed;

    public static Path2D.Double function;

    //The frame enclosing the graphing canvas
    private static JFrame frame;
    //The graphing canvas
    private static JPanel canvas = new JPanel() {
        private static final int DEFAULT_CANVAS_SIZE = 600;

        //Ensures the frame initialized to the right size
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(DEFAULT_CANVAS_SIZE, DEFAULT_CANVAS_SIZE);
        }

        //Paints the graph whenever it needs updating
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            super.paintComponent(g2);

            xScale = getWidth() / (xMax - xMin);
            yScale = getHeight() / (yMax - yMin);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            try {
                g2.draw(function);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    /**
     * I'm using the function y = exp(x) as an example. Feel free to replace it.
     * @param x the x-value
     * @return exp(x), the y-value
     */
    private static double getYVal(double x) {
        return Math.exp(x);
    }

    //Initializes the function path
    public static void initPath() {
        final double STEP_X = (xMax - xMin) / canvas.getWidth();

        function = new Path2D.Double();

        double x = xMin;
        double y = getYVal(x);

        function.moveTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(y));
        for(x = xMin + STEP_X; x <= xMax; x += STEP_X) {
            y = getYVal(x);
            function.lineTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(y));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the pixel x-coordinate on the canvas
     * that corresponds to a given x-value of the function
     * @param x the x-value of the function
     * @return the adjusted x-coordinate
     */
    private static int getGraphX(double x) {
        return (int) (canvas.getWidth() * (x - xMin) / (xMax - xMin));
    }

    //Same thing as getGraphX except for y-coords
    private static int getGraphY(double y) {
        return (int) (canvas.getHeight() * (yMax - y) / (yMax - yMin));
    }

    /*
     * This is probably where the problem is, this extends the path so that it
     *      covers the entire visible range
     */
    public static void updateFunctionBounds(double dx) {

        double newXMin = xMin - dx / xScale;
        double newXMax = xMax - dx / xScale;

        final int WIDTH = canvas.getWidth();
        final double STEP_X = (xMax - xMin) / WIDTH;
        double drawTo;

        if((drawTo = newXMin) < xMin && drawTo < minXGraphed) {
            minXGraphed = drawTo;

            double x = drawTo;
            function.moveTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));

            for(x = drawTo + STEP_X; x < xMin; x += STEP_X) {
                function.lineTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));
            }

            x = xMin;
            function.lineTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));

        } else if((drawTo = newXMax) > xMax && drawTo > maxXGraphed) {
            maxXGraphed = drawTo;

            double x = xMax;
            function.moveTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));

            for(x = xMax + STEP_X; x < drawTo; x += STEP_X) {
                function.lineTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));
            }

            x = drawTo;
            function.lineTo(getGraphX(x), getGraphY(getYVal(x)));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initBounds();
        initFrame();
    }

    //Initializes the graph boundaries. Feel free to change this
    private static void initBounds() {
        xMin = yMin = minXGraphed = -10;
        xMax = yMax = maxXGraphed = 10;
    }

    //Initializes the frame and a MouseAdapter that controls the scrolling
    private static void initFrame() {
        MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e);
                lastPointer[0] = e.getX();
                lastPointer[1] = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseDragged(e);
                AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
                double dx = e.getX() - lastPointer[0];
                double dy = e.getY() - lastPointer[1];
                t.translate(dx, dy);

                updateFunctionBounds(dx);
                function.transform(t);

                xMin -= dx / xScale;
                xMax -= dx / xScale;
                yMin -= dy / yScale;
                yMax -= dy / yScale;

                canvas.repaint();

                lastPointer[0] = e.getX();
                lastPointer[1] = e.getY();
            }
        };
        canvas.addMouseListener(adapter);
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(adapter);

        frame = new JFrame("Minimal Reproducible Approach");
        frame.setContentPane(canvas);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        initPath();
        canvas.repaint();
    }
}
```

If it was working correctly, the stitching would be seamless and the function would smoothly scroll as the mouse pointer was dragged across the canvas, sort of like it does in Desmos. In reality, it doesn't retain the correct height (y-value) and doesn't actually connect to the previous segments in all cases.

Thank you for any and all help!

Edit: I've updated the code into what I think is a minimal reproducible example.